# How to find erase and line kill character for ubuntu 12.10

Tags: command-line

I'm new to Unix and have bought today a copy of "The Unix Programming Environment". I'm trying out the stuff from the book. But some of them are not working as expected like : To kill a line and re-type it again, @ character should be used :

**book**

```
$ ddtae@
date
Thu Nov 28 18:12:47 IST 2013
```

my terminal

```
$ ddtae@
ddtae@: command not found
```

Another example is to use # to erase last character

**book**

```
$ dd#att#e#e
```

which comes out as date and print it.

**my terminal**

```
$ dd#att#e#e
dd#att#e#e: command not found
```

in my system # is used for commment

Although they have mentioned that these characters are system dependent. How can i find the characters for my system to perform above two tasks.

Comment: You bought the wrong book mate, Ubuntu is not Unix. There is plenty of stuff that works differently, especially if go with low level programming.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102940/how-to-find-erase-and-line-kill-character-for-ubuntu-12-10 hmm?

Answer (score 0):

The [Unix Programming Environment... From 1983/4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unix_Programming_Environment)?

I'm honestly not sure how much use their terminal stuff is going to be. Bash has changed a bit since... Hang on, Bash didn't exist until '89.

It's a good book (I tried to read it while I was at uni and failed miserably) but you can't take the examples as written anymore. A lot of the C stuff should still work though.

Answer (score 0):

The book is still correct, when it says that these things are system dependent. That said in bash (and at least zsh) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> should delete everything left of your cursor and a simple <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>) should delete one character left of your cursor.

As for finding out such things:

If you are using bash (the default on ubuntu) `man bash` especially the section on "READLINE" will have some pointers.

With zsh you can find a list of configured key bindings with thie `bindkey` command.